# AJAX: Display Chart data as IMG

Tags: php, ajax, charts, image

I want to show a (chart) image using AJAX. I'm not sure what's wrong, but I'm getting the following 'error' and an incorrect image:
"|xtt�I������{饗BBBN�:��}�̛7oРA7n�0l߾} QQQIIIeee�aLHH������ضm��wm���v��U�&�Z���o�# Art]]]����{���#""��'���v|�ҥKqqq���ح�~;11�ȑ#����޺u��ںm6O�7o���.��ի��?~Ȑ!��~��۷��O�0A.�cv�����TäR)�� ����˗{N����5<��&0� ���ҷo��@�NХ<0�j�0��=���]�t��۷�j�T*5�\����۳g�F�����gfm���ݻ�'OF....."

The code I'm using:

**ajax_select.php:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var xmlhttp;

function showUser(str,age)
{
xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
  return;
  }
var url="test_ajax.php";
url=url+"?q="+str+"&a="+age;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="<IMG SRC='" + xmlhttp.responseText + "'/>";
}
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  // code for IE6, IE5
  return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
return null;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select id="users" name="users">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<?php

$con = mysql_connect(***);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("***", $con);

$sql="SELECT ***";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
</select>

<select id="age" name="age">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<?php

$con = mysql_connect('***');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("***", $con);

$sql="SELECT ***";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  }

mysql_close($con);

?>
</select>

<input type='button' value='Refresh Data' onclick="showUser(document.getElementById('users').value,document.getElementById('age').value)">
</form>

<br><br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>chart will be displayed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**ajax_select_NEW.php:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var xmlhttp;

function showUser(str,age)
{
var url = 'test_ajax.php';
url += '?q=' + str + '&a=' + age + '&sid=' + Math.random();

document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = '<img src="' + url + '" />';

xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
  return;
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}


function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  // code for IE6, IE5
  return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
return null;
}

</script>
```

**test_ajax.php:**

```
<?php
/* Include the pData class */
include("class/pData.class.php");
include("class/pDraw.class.php");
include("class/pImage.class.php");

/* Get user from AJAX resquest */
$user_id=$_GET["q"];

$q=$_GET["q"];
$a=$_GET["a"];

/* Create the pData object */
$MyData = new pData();  

/* Connect to the MySQL database */
$db = mysql_connect("***");
mysql_select_db("***",$db);




/* Build the query that will returns the data to graph */

$Requete = "

SELECT ***
";

***
/* Render the picture (choose the best way) */
$myPicture->autoOutput("examples/example.drawBarChart.png");

?>
```

I have hard coded the variables in the SQL code for now. (in test_ajax.php) So if I open that page it just shows the correct chart image. But when I open the ajax_select.php page I get the error in the picture above. (so it's not a wrong chart code information, since it's okay if I open the php page directly)

I have searched a lot, but can't find the solution. Hopefully someone can help me here, would be much appreciated!

Comment: could you please check your response text by alerting it like : alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

Comment: I did this and got the same text I see on the page where the image needs to be displayed: �PNG



IHDR��I+/� IDATx���y\TU��;�8��* �"h ����[�H���Ff�ie�Zj�Dffjnm���� ......"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to put the binary image data into the `src` attribute of the `img`. This attribute is meant for the source URL of the image, you can do this entirely without `XmlHttpRequest`, just insert your image by using `test_ajax.php` as the `src`.

```
function showUser(str, age) {
    var url = 'test_ajax.php';
    url += '?q=' + str + '&a=' + age + '&sid=' + Math.random();

    document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = '<img src="' + url + '" />';
}
```

As for the broken rendering of the image, have you included a `Content-Type`-header?

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$myPicture->autoOutput("examples/example.drawBarChart.png");
```

---

This is what **ajax_select_NEW.php** should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str, age) {
    var url = 'test_ajax.php';
    url += '?q=' + str + '&a=' + age + '&sid=' + Math.random();

    document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = '<img src="' + url + '" />';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now! I didn't had to change the Content-Type-header, but your function works perfectly and solved the problem. I think I placed the '    document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = '<img src="' + url + '" />';' in the wrong function..

Comment: Sure, I wanted to do that but can't find the 'answer' button? (is it the 'Post Your Answer' at the bottom of the page? :)) Btw, one more question if possible: is it okay to put the var url and "  document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = '<img src="' + url + '" />';
" right after the "function showUser(str,age) {"? See my edited first post (ajax_select_NEW.php). I just want to know if that script is okay, than I'm done. (because if I put the var url etc. in a seperate function (ajax_select.php), it doesn't work...) But I'm not totally sure if this is the right solution. Thanks once more.

Comment: You can leave out the whole `XmlHttpRequest` part, you don't need it. The only thing in the `<script>` tags should be the function I gave you. I edited my post. As for accepting an answer: http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Comment: Thanks again. I wasn't sure if I could leave out the seperate code for old (IE)browsers etc. Answer is now solved!